# How to adjust floating elements?

Tags: html, css

How could I adjust floating elements in CSS?
For the code below I got result as on attached picture.
I would like to have left and right divs aligned vertically.

```css
* {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  background: #C0FFC0;
}

.header {
  background: #C0C0FF;
  height: 100px;
}

.left {
  background: #FFC0C0;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 25%;
}

.right {
  background: #FFFFC0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}

.bottom {
  background: #C0FFFF;
  clear: both;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<div class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<div class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<div class="bottom">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap left and right divs inside another div **(main)** and you are good to go.

```css
* {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  background: #C0FFC0;
}

.header {
  background: #C0C0FF;
  height: 100px;
}

.main {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.left {
  background: #FFC0C0;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 25%;
}

.right {
  background: #FFFFC0;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bottom {
  background: #C0FFFF;
  clear: both;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
  <div class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
```

Comment: I see. Thanks! I just wanted to have the left column width to be 25% and right remaining 75%, but I cannot use 75% when I use 10px margin or padding. Therefore I wanted to have the right column with width set to remaining size.

Comment: @noonespecial you can use width on the right column as well and add `float:right` to position it on the right side .. see my updated answer

Comment: I tried both and it does not work. When margin and padding of "main" class is set to 0, the issue is as on the picture above. However, when  float=right is set, the size of the right column is not adopting to available space.

Comment: @noonespecial you need to add `overflow:hidden` to main class to fix the issue, and for the right column size i'm not sure i understand what u wanna achieve, i just showed that u can use width on it.